# MySql got problem with duplicate column name

Tags: mysql, sql

so I was following this SQL tutorial on youtube and I followed everything he did and I ended up with this code

```
CREATE TABLE user_data (
    id INT,
    username VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

ALTER TABLE user_data ADD gpa DECIMAL(3,2);
```

but turns out I got this error:

```
ALTER TABLE user_data ADD gpa DECIMAL(3,2)  Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'gpa'   0.000 sec.
```

I used MySql Workbench as my editor also this is my first time learning SQL and I don't understand the error at all. Please help?

Comment: Type show create table user_data , examine result , is there a column gpa?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code once:

```
ALTER TABLE user_data ADD COLUMN gpa DECIMAL(3,2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!. But unfortunately the same error still appears.

Comment: It should be working I suppose

Comment: ALTER TABLE user_data MODIFY IF EXISTS column gpa DECIMAL(3,2);

Comment: Are you mounting a database beforehand?  User_data is .. sorta reserved in mysql